# Alias a field name in mongo compass

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo (Compass), I'm trying to follow other SO answers to return an aliased field name.

For example, in my `people` collection there is a "n" property which gives me the "name".

I have tried these different variations, which all show an error warning.

Is this possible and I'm doing something wrong?

```
{"n": "name"}
{"$n": "name"}
{"name": "n"}
{"name": "$n"}
```

[image: error]

Comment: This should work `{ $project: { name: '$n' }}`

Answer (score 0):

If your option in your query bar is Project you must set which fields to return. Specify the field and 1 to include a field or 0 to exclude a field.

```
{"name":1}
```

You can see [Query Bar][1] for more information
https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/query-bar/

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to return an alias, not just return the field using `{n: 1}`

Comment: My answer is showing the why of the error warning, you shouldn't use "Project" then, checkout the documentation for "Project" in the query bar.
https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/query/project/#query-bar-project
That's what I mean, you have to use just or 1 or 0